# resolving threading conflicts in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

lets suppose there is a static variable accessed by 2 threads.

```
public static int val = 1;
```

now suppose thread 1 execute's a statement like this

```
if(val==1)
{
  val +=1
}
```

However after the check and before the addition in the above statement thread 2 changes the value of val to something else.

Now that would cause some nasty error. And this is happening in my code.

Is there any way that thread 1 gets noticed that the values of val has been changed and it instead of adding goes back and performs the check again.

Comment: Based on your question, I'd suggest `Interlocked.CompareExchange`, as recommended in the answer below. If you think that's not appropriate, you should change your question to show us the *real* problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 6):

Specifically for your example, you could:

```
var originalValue = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref val, 
                                    2,       //update val to this value
                                    1);      //if val matches this value
if(originalValue == 1)
{
    //the update occurred
}
```

Comment: well my example was just a simplified version of the problem i am facing in my code. I don't think the above method would be very easy to use in my real code.

Comment: @WinCoder : Take a look at what Interlocked has to offer, because it may still have the tools to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a lock:

```
var lockObj = new object();

if(val == 1) // is the value what we want
{
    lock(lockObj) // let's lock it
    {
        if(val == 1) // now that it's lock, check again just to be sure
        {
            val += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

If going that route, you'll have to make sure any code that modifies `val` also uses a lock with the same lock object.

```
lock(lockObj)
{
    // code that changes `val`
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like a great idea to check the value of val outside the lock and then do it again inside the lock. If you put every access to val within a lock, whether it is read or write, you don't need to worry about someone messing with it before you touch it. Therefore you get the lock and then check the val, and you can be sure no one else is touching val before you do.

Comment: @MichaelMankus - In your case, you wind up taking a lock whether you need it or not. Checking a value is typically inexpensive whereas taking a lock is more expensive and can hold up other code waiting for a lock. Check out the reasoning at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: Good point. I've never double-checked around my locks. Looks like it's something I'll start doing.

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd use a lock here instead of `Interlocked.CompareExchange`.

Comment: @JimMischel - I used a lock simply because I assumed this was a simplified example. If the OP really is only incrementing the value, then certainly would go with Iterlocked.CompareExchange or Interlocked.Increment method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lock around accessing val or updating val.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to increment an integral value in a thread-safe way, you can use the static `Interlocked.Increment` method: [Interlocked.Increment Method (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx)